# how to fix non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, mysql-python

am trying to insert data from the MySQLdb table into Treeview,and on running the program i receive a syntax Error: non-keyword arg after keyword arg.i don't know what it means i request for explanation and how i can solve it.
`

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import MySQLdb

root = Tk()
root.geometry("320x240")

tree = ttk.Treeview(root)

conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "drake", "OSCAR")
cursor = conn.cursor()

tree["columns"] = ("one", "two", "three")
tree.column("one", width=100)
tree.column("two", width=100)
tree.column("three", width=100)

tree.heading("#0", text='ID', anchor='w')
tree.column("#0", anchor="w")
tree.heading("one", text="NAME")
tree.heading("two", text="VOTES")
tree.heading("three", text="PERSENTAGE")

for i in range(1, 6):
    cursor.execute("""select name from president where ID =%s""", (i,))
    nm = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    cursor.execute("""select votes from president where ID =%s""", (i,))
    vot = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    cursor.execute("""select percentage from president where ID =%s""",(i,))
    percent = cursor.fetchone()[0]

    tree.insert("", i, text=i, values=(nm, vot, percent)),

tree.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

`

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace.

Comment: Keyword arguments in function signatures are optional. Non-keyword arguments are positional. Therefore they should always come first. I don't see a violation of that rule in the function calls shown above.

Comment: syntax error is derived from `tree.insert("", i, text=i, values=(nm, vot, percent))`@kevin

Comment: Works fine on my machine. Are you 100% sure that the code you're running is exactly identical to the code you're showing us here?

Comment: its the same code @kevin

Comment: can the problem be coming from the way i fetch or the data fetched because i still receive the same problem @roadrunner66